# Ecto.migrate create database schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am just getting started with Elixir/Phoenix and Ecto migrations. I cannot find a way to create Postgres database schemas using migrations. My database will need up to 4 different schemas in the near future. I mean doing this, but creating a schema instead of a table. I'm not sure it can be done, but if so, how? Thanks.

```
  def change do
    create table(:people) do
      ...
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**`Ecto.Migration.execute/1`**](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1) function is what you're looking for. You can use it to execute arbitrary SQL commands, like creating users, schemas, or adding extensions to the database.

```
defmodule Example.Migrations.MakeSchema do
  use Ecto.Migration

  execute "CREATE SCHEMA example"
end
```